# useForm from react-hook-form doesn't catch error from zod

Tags: reactjs, validation, next.js, react-hook-form, zod

`errors` array is empty when validation does not pass in refine. I expect that an error should appear there with the message "This phone number looks wrong".

`useForm` validates the entire form correctly (`isValid` changes correctly, but the error for `refine` is missing in the `errors` array). `errors` update well for fields inside z.object({...}).

For debugging, I added `console.log` inside `refine`. Logging `"VALID"` and `"INVALID"` works fine, but even when I log `"INVALID"` there is still no `error` in the `errors` array.

useForm:

```
const {
  register,
  handleSubmit,
  watch,
  setValue,
  formState: { errors, isSubmitting, isValid, isDirty, dirtyFields },
} = useForm<UpdateEmployeeFormData>({
  mode: "onTouched",
  resolver: zodResolver(profileEditSchema),
  defaultValues,
});

console.log(errors);
```

profileEditSchema:

```
...

export const profileEditSchema = z
  .object({
    ...mandatoryFields,
    ...optionalFields,
  })
  .refine(
    (data) => {
      const phoneNumber = data.phoneNumberPrefix + data.phoneNumberWithoutPrefix;
      try {
        phoneNumberValidation.parse(phoneNumber);
        console.log("VALID");
        return true;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("INVALID");
        return false;
      }
    },
    {
      message: "This phone number looks wrong",
      path: ["phoneNumber"],
    }
  );
```

Comment: Can you also update your question with the Form and inputs?